# Can i increase the click duration on the button clicked

Tags: button, kivy, python-3.6, duration

The button when it is pressed becomes blue and on release it goes back to normal.What i'm asking is if i could make the button stay clicked longer.Without using the clock modules.Can i use "duration" on my button.If anyone could put an example that would be really helpful.I don't have anywhere else to check.I have checked all links that came up on google.Expecting a help.Thank you.

Comment: Why do you need the button to stay in clicked state?

Comment: when the button is clicked a label animation function is working...so if i could put a duration on the button to stay clicked until animation is finished then back to usual unclicked state..it would make the code pretty easy...i am just learning,sorry if what i asked is stupid

Comment: Add duration to label animation instead of adding it to button. If you want your button to be unclickable while the animation is in progress, add disabled attribute to your button.